# How can I have Emacs ruby-mode highlight symbols in the Ruby 1.9 style?

Tags: ruby, emacs, ruby-1.9, ruby-mode

Using Emacs 24.3.1, I would like to have symbols used in hashes with the trailing colon style introduced at Ruby 1.9.x highlighted as it highlights leading colon symbols. Is this possible?

### Screenshot:

[image: Different highlighting for symbols]

Comment: Which OS are you running on? On Ubuntu and Emacs 24.3 it highlights fine.

Comment: It's more likely to be the Emacs version than the OS that's important here, as `ruby-mode` is built into Emacs.

Comment: OS/X 10.9.5. Emacs 24.3.1. ruby-mode.el is 1.1, copyright 2008, so pretty old. I'll see about upgrading that.

Comment: *Update*: upgrading to ruby-mode.el 1.2 fixes this.